# Vectorized conditional outputs in R (maybe using purrr)?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, purrr

I am trying to create vectorized conditional outputs of a data frame.

Suppose I have the dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(5, 3, 9, 5),
                   b = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   c = c(5, 3, 9, 5),
                   d = c(5, 3, 9, 5))
```

And the threshold:

```
threshold <- c(a1 = 4, b1 = 2, c1 = 8, d1 = 2)
```

What I want is a new dataset that indicates whether each value of a is greater than or equal to the corresponding value in the threshold vector (a1), each value of b is greater than or equal to the corresponding value in the threshold vector (b1), etc.

So the desired output would be:

```
desired_data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 0, 1, 1),
                           b = c(0, 1, 1, 1),
                           c = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
                           d = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I want to do this as simply as possible, ideally using a `purrr` function.

Here is a wrong attempt:

`desired_data <- map(data >= threshold)`

I feel like `map2` might be promising, and have checked the documentation (e.g., [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) and [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html)) but I can't seem to get the syntax for conditional outputs based on mapping.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the idea with `map2()`: since a data frame is a list of column, you can loop on the columns. The small difficulty is to put everything in a data frame at the end, it's done automatically if you use `map2_df()`.

```
map2_df(threshold, data, ~ .y >= .x)
```

And if you want these logical values to be converted to integers:

```
1L * map2_df(threshold, data, ~ .y >= .x)
#   a1 b1 c1 d1
# 1  1  0  0  1
# 2  0  0  0  1
# 3  1  1  1  1
# 4  1  1  0  1
```

Comment: brilliant, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note that the solution uses `>` instead of `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `sweep` in base R. However, the output is a matrix and has to be converted to data.frame:

```
as.data.frame(1L * sweep(data, 2, threshold, FUN=">="))
#   a b c d
# 1 1 0 0 1
# 2 0 1 0 1
# 3 1 1 1 1
# 4 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pmap` from the `purrr` package.

```r
library(purrr)

data <- data.frame(a = c(5, 3, 9, 5),
                   b = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                   c = c(5, 3, 9, 5),
                   d = c(5, 3, 9, 5))

desired_data <- data.frame(a = c(1, 0, 1, 1),
                           b = c(0, 1, 1, 1),
                           c = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
                           d = c(1, 1, 1, 1))

threshold <- c(a1 = 4, b1 = 2, c1 = 8, d1 = 2)

output <- pmap(list(data, threshold), ~ .x >= .y)

as.data.frame(1L * do.call(cbind, output))

#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 0 0 1
#> 2 0 1 0 1
#> 3 1 1 1 1
#> 4 1 1 0 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you can use replicate to create a matrix with each row containing the the thresholds: 1st row has `a`s .... then transpose and compare it with data, make it a data.frame then add 0 to convert the values to numeric :

```r
data.frame( data >= t(replicate(nrow(data), threshold)) ) + 0
```

```r
  a b c d
1 1 0 0 1
2 0 1 0 1
3 1 1 1 1
4 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option :

```
+t(t(data) >= threshold)

#     a b c d
#[1,] 1 0 0 1
#[2,] 0 1 0 1
#[3,] 1 1 1 1
#[4,] 1 1 0 1
```